# XAML for Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am building an app in Windows Phone 7.
I am showing a few data in different TextBlocks.
But as the data size is too big, it doesn't fit in my view.
I want to show the data like a paragraph.
If the data size exceeds the size of the emulator I want to put a ScrollBar so that the data can be scrolled and viewed.
Please help me.
I am providing my XAML design.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,17,12,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">

        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Height="63" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,43,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="News Details"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="308" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="48"  Foreground="AntiqueWhite"/>

        <TextBlock Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,333,0,0" Name="date" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="173" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="24" />

        <TextBlock Height="43" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,397,0,0" Name="title" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="373" />

        <TextBlock Height="206" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,462,0,0" Name="description" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="373" />

        <Image Height="167" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,113,0,0" Name="newsimage" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="368" />


    </Grid>

    <Button x:Name="previous" BorderThickness="0" Click="Image_Back" Margin="0,23,431,682" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="76" Height="63" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Image/Previous.png" />
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: scrolling is not a textblocks behaviour, you could use a textbox instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,17,12,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">

 <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"  TextAlignment="Center" Height="63" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,43,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="News Details"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="308" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="48"  Foreground="AntiqueWhite"/>  

            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"  Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,333,0,0" Name="date" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="173" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="24" />

            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"  Height="43" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,397,0,0" Name="title" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="373" />

            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"  Height="206" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,462,0,0" Name="description" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="373" />

            <Image Height="167" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,113,0,0" Name="newsimage" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="368" />

    </Grid>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

More details

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/scrollviewer-not-scrollable

Comment: Its not working. Please see my complete code i am posting now. Moreover the texblock1 is a heading which shouldnot come in scroll.

Comment: You cannot use wrapping if you want the user to scroll you must choose one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Scrollable textblock. Hope that help you to solve the issue.